# weak property cannot be initialized in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

So here's a definition in swift:

```
@objc(ChartAxisBase)
open class AxisBase: ComponentBase
{
    public override init()
    {
        super.init()
    }

    /// Custom formatter that is used instead of the auto-formatter if set
    weak fileprivate var _axisValueFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter?
}
```

and here is getter and setter for `valueFormatter`:

```
open var valueFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter?
{
    get
    {
        if _axisValueFormatter == nil ||
            (_axisValueFormatter is DefaultAxisValueFormatter &&
                (_axisValueFormatter as! DefaultAxisValueFormatter).hasAutoDecimals &&
                (_axisValueFormatter as! DefaultAxisValueFormatter).decimals != decimals)
        {
            let df = DefaultAxisValueFormatter(decimals: decimals)
            _axisValueFormatter = df
            NSLog("found nil vf, assigning to \(_axisValueFormatter)")
        }
        NSLog("returning _axisValueFormatter: \(_axisValueFormatter)")
        return _axisValueFormatter
    }
    set
    {
        _axisValueFormatter = newValue ?? DefaultAxisValueFormatter(decimals: decimals)
    }
}
```

The setter will detect if `_axisValueFormatter` is nil, it will create a default one for it and return.

However, later in a objective-C file, I tried to initialize it like:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    ChartXAxis *xAxis = _chartView.xAxis;
    ChartDefaultAxisValueFormatter *f = [[ChartDefaultAxisValueFormatter alloc] initWithFormatter:leftAxisFormatter];
    xAxis.valueFormatter = [[ChartDefaultAxisValueFormatter alloc] initWithFormatter:leftAxisFormatter];
    NSLog(@"x axis vf:%@", xAxis.valueFormatter);

    ChartYAxis *leftAxis = _chartView.leftAxis;
    leftAxis.valueFormatter = [[ChartDefaultAxisValueFormatter alloc] initWithFormatter:leftAxisFormatter];
    NSLog(@"left axis vf:%@", leftAxis.valueFormatter);
}
```

`xAxis.valueFormatter` and `leftAxis.valueFormatter`now is nil according to log:

```
2017-01-11 12:38:25.819 ChartsDemo[49440:3296871] found nil vf, assigning to Optional(<ChartDefaultAxisValueFormatter: 0x608000268480>)
2017-01-11 12:38:25.820 ChartsDemo[49440:3296871] returning nil
2017-01-11 12:38:25.820 ChartsDemo[49440:3296871] x axis vf:(null)
2017-01-11 12:38:25.821 ChartsDemo[49440:3296871] found nil vf, assigning to Optional(<ChartDefaultAxisValueFormatter: 0x608000269e80>)
2017-01-11 12:38:25.821 ChartsDemo[49440:3296871] returning nil
2017-01-11 12:38:25.821 ChartsDemo[49440:3296871] left axis vf:(null)
```

However,

If I change like this for `leftAxis`:

```
ChartDefaultAxisValueFormatter *lf = [[ChartDefaultAxisValueFormatter alloc] initWithFormatter:leftAxisFormatter];
leftAxis.valueFormatter = lf;
NSLog(@"left axis vf:%@", leftAxis.valueFormatter);
```

leftAxis will have a formatter for now:

```
2017-01-11 12:40:26.147 ChartsDemo[49582:3311643] returning Optional(<ChartDefaultAxisValueFormatter: 0x608000265cc0>)
2017-01-11 12:40:26.147 ChartsDemo[49582:3311643] left axis vf:<ChartDefaultAxisValueFormatter: 0x608000265cc0>
```

I know it's not a good user case because it's weak, after `viewDidLoad()` finishes, it should all be gone, but just stick to the log, I am very confused now, I don't think creating a new pointer will matter so much. I think I should make a silly mistake, but just too blind to see it at the moment.

For anyone that can help, please download the whole project from:
https://github.com/liuxuan30/Charts/archive/Weak.zip

You can replace the viewDidLoad counterpart with my code in `BarChartViewController.m` as example.

It might need you to install `Realm` via `carthage bootstrap` in order to run ChartsDemo.

Answer (score 0):

On this line it looks like you are constructing a new object and assigning it to the weak reference:

```
 _axisValueFormatter = newValue ?? DefaultAxisValueFormatter(decimals: decimals)
```

You can't do that because it will have a retain count of zero (weak references do not call retain).  Therefore it will be immediately released because thats what happens when your retain count goes to 0 and your newly created object is deinitialized.  Somebody needs to keep a strong reference to the object.

Is there a reason why this needs to be weak?  Weak is typically used to break a retain cycle, but I don't think your DefaultAxisValueFormatter is retaining your AxisBase instance because you aren't passing it into the constructor.

Your objective C code has the same problem.  You initialize a strong reference and assign it to the variable f, which is on the stack (your retain count is 1).  You assign f to your weak reference (your retain count is still 1), then f goes out of scope, your retain count drops to 0 and the object is deallocated; your weak reference now points to nil.  Hoist f into a property that exists for the life of the class instead of just viewDidLoad and it should fix the problem, but I think its better to get rid of weak altogether unless you have a compelling use for it.

Comment: thanks, does `someFormatter = DefaultAxisValueFormatter(decimals: decimals); _formatter = someFormatter` and `_formatter = DefaultAxisValueFormatter(decimals: decimals)` are different in terms of retain count? I suppose they have the same effect, because `_formatter = DefaultAxisValueFormatter(decimals: decimals)` will use something like `autorelease()` while returning, so it should be dealloc when pool drains or after function ends, but you said "it will be immediately released", is there any documentation for it?

Comment: in terms of using weak, it's an open source project, somebody asks they will use 'self' as the delegate (the formatter is kind of delegate), so it causes retain circle. At first, we think using weak can solve this, but when I tested it, I found the above issues, that's why we asked this. We have dropped using weak. I just want to know what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: DefaultAxisValueFormatter is autoreleased so its not released "immediately" but rather int he very near future.  If the user wants to use self as the IAxisValueFormatter then the property should be weak.  Instead of assigning it to an instance of DefaultAxisValueFormatter(decimals: decimals) make a second private static let defaultAxisValueFormatter = DefaultAxisValueFormatter(decimals: decimals) and assign _axisValueFormatter = newValue ?? defaultAxisValueFormatter.  Now you will have a strong reference.  This doesn't fix ChartDefaultAxisValueFormatter.  Maybe that can be a lazy singleton?

Comment: I just tested, if I use let someF = Formatter(); _axisValueFormatter = someF and when the getter returns, _axisValueFormatter is nil. That's why I am confused, you can check my log above: `2017-01-11 12:38:25.819 ChartsDemo[49440:3296871] found nil vf, assigning to Optional(<ChartDefaultAxisValueFormatter: 0x608000268480>)
2017-01-11 12:38:25.820 ChartsDemo[49440:3296871] returning nil`, first you see it actually assign to a valid object, but right after that, _axisValueFormatter is nil, even before the getter returns